# Three.js: Unable to Set Maximum and Minimum Zoom Level

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am using this example for my WebGL panorama cube:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=pano#webgl_panorama_equirectangular

I want to zoom in and out within limits, i.e. set maximum and minimum zoom level, but not infinitely as code provides by default. For infinite zoom, which later reverses the view if scrolled too much, the function from example above looks like this:

```
    function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
            camera.fov += event.deltaY * 0.05;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
```

To address the issue I tried to update FOV when inside my allowed range:

```
    function onDocumentMouseWheel( event ) {
        var fovMAX = 95;
        var fovMIN = 5;
        var newFov = camera.fov + event.deltaY * 0.05;
        if (newFov > fovMIN && newFov < fovMAX) {
            camera.fov = newFov;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        };
    }
```

Please note my FOV is 90:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight), 0.1, 100 );
```

This seems to have perfectly worked for maximum zoomed-in level - it stops when FOV is 5 and does not zoom in further. However, as I zoom out to FOV 95, it would stop, but if I continue zooming out with mouse more, I would zoom infinitely again, even though FOV remains 95.

How to stop/control infinite zoom out?

Comment: are you using the orbit controller or something like that?

Comment: Yes OrbitController I am using

Comment: That might be overriding your values. Can you disable it and test just your zoom logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as expected in the minimal example below. (I did make a small change in that I'm using `>=`/`<=` rather than `>`/`<`.)

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  FOV = 35,
  NEAR = 1,
  FAR = 1000;

var fovMax = 95,
  fovMin = 5,
  fovTmp = 0;

function zoom(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fovTmp = camera.fov + (event.deltaY * 0.05);
  if (fovTmp >= fovMin && fovTmp <= fovMax) {
    camera.fov = fovTmp;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function init() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.padding = "0";

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera.position.z = 50;
  scene.add(camera);

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera.add(light);

  stats = new Stats();
  stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
  document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

  resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

  // POPULATE EXAMPLE
  var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "red"
    });
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(mesh);

  window.addEventListener("wheel", zoom);

  animate();
}

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  if (renderer && camera) {
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
  init();
}

(function() {
  function addScript(url, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.addEventListener("load", callback);
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function() {
    addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function() {
      threeReady();
    })
  })
})();
```

Something else is changing your camera's data. Are you sure you're not updating `camera.zoom` anywhere?

For what it's worth, the only other (core) three.js method that modifies the FOV is [`PerspectiveCamera.setFocalLength`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.setFocalLength)

**Edit based on new information**

Ah, there's your problem. I didn't know you were using an external mouse controller. `OrbitControls` doesn't adjust the FOV to create its zoom effect. Instead, it literally moves the camera nearer to/further from the control's `target`. Your zoom-in likely (by chance) corresponded with it reaching 0 distance. But because it can zoom out to infinity, that's why it continued to zoom out.

Disabling zoom like in your comment should resolve the issue.

three.js r87

Comment: Thank you. I found the problem that this line was causing the issue: camera.position.z = 0.01; However, when I remove it I can no longer pan the image. The zoom stops at maximum zoom-out but how can I handle panning now?

Comment: I think I found the solution: I need these lines to exist: `controls.enableZoom = false; controls.enablePan = false;`

Comment: @Vad I've edited my answer with a little more info on `OrbitControls`.